# display data after selecting options from dropdown codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm very new here and also to codeigniter and Ajax.

I need to display data after selecting from the drop down option without reloading the page / submit button. It displays after the option is selected as I'm able to properly display data for the options, now I just need to display data based on that option on two separate fields.

For example :

> paket : paket 1
>
> description : its something something
>
> jadwal : soon to be announced

the options are the product, the one I need to be displayed on their separate fields is the description on `description` field and jadwal on `jadwal` field.

Here is the code I have for the view:

```php
//this is the code for the options

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="paket">Pilih Paket</label>
    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="paket" id="paket">
      <option value="">Pilih Paket</option>
        <?php  
            foreach ($datatour as $dttour) 
            {
                if ($id==$dttour->id) 
                {
                    $s='selected';
                }
                else
                {
                    $s='';
                }
            ?>
                <option <?php echo $s ?>  value="<?php echo $dttour->id;?>"><?php echo $dttour->paket;?></option>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8" align="left">
        <label for="jadwal">Jadwal</label>
        <div style="border:1px solid #ccc;text-align:left;background-color:white;">

            // this is where i display the jadwal data

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="kolom" style="border:1px solid #ccc;background-color:white;overflow:auto;" align="center">
        <div class="row">
            <h3>Detail Paket</h3> <br>

        // this is where i display the description data

        <p></p>
        </div>

</div>
```

I haven't written any code for the models and the controllers, any help and explanation of the process (if that's not much to ask) would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate your view in two views:

**First view:** named *sand_main.php* in folder *sandbox_v*

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="paket">Pilih Paket</label>
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="paket" id="paket">
      <option selected value="">Pilih Paket</option> 
      <option value="123">123</option>
      <option value="324">566</option>
      <option value="555">333</option>
       <!-- I've used my own code, for checking the result, you should use your:
       <option value="">Pilih Paket</option>
        <?php  
            foreach ($datatour as $dttour) 
            {
                if ($id==$dttour->id) 
                {
                    $s='selected';
                }
                else
                {
                    $s='';
                }
            ?>
                <option <?php echo $s ?>  value="<?php echo $dttour->id;?>"><?php echo $dttour->paket;?></option>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
       -->      
    </select>
</div>

<div id="info"></div>
```

Where **JS** should be next:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $('#paket').unbind('change');
    $('#paket').change(function(){

    var opt_sel = $('#paket').val();  

        $.ajax({
            method:"POST", 
            url:'/index.php/sandbox/s1',
            data:{
                sel_op:opt_sel
            }
        }).done(function(a){

            $('#info').html(a);
        }).fail(function(){

            alert("It's an epic fail.");
        });
    });

})
</script>
```

**Second view:** named *sand_view_2.php* in folder *sandbox_v*

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8" align="left">
        <label for="jadwal">Jadwal</label>
        <div style="border:1px solid #ccc;text-align:left;background-color:white;">

            <?= $j_info; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="kolom" style="border:1px solid #ccc;background-color:white;overflow:auto;" align="center">
        <div class="row">
            <h3>Detail Paket</h3> <br>

            <?= $d_info; ?>

        <p></p>
        </div>

</div>
```

**Controller:** in my example *sandbox.php*

```
<?php
class Sandbox extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(); 
    }

    public function index() { 
        // here you should get your $datatour data          

        $this->load->view('sandbox_v/sand_main.php', [
                            'datatour'     => $datatour 
                                ]);
    }

    public function s1() { 

        $sel_val = $this->input->post('sel_op');

        /*you can use your DB for getting a description for each value
         * in this case you should add in __construct() your model as $this->load->model('your_model);  
         * or use your DB connection directly here.
         */ 

        /* with your model:
         * $jdwal_info =  $this->your_model->your_jdwal($sel_val); 
         * $detail_info =  $this->your_model->your_detail($sel_val); 
         */

        // without. It means that you've got info in the other way, for example, in predefined way:

        if ($sel_val == 555) {

            $jdwal_info = 'descr 1';
            $detail_info = 'detail 1';
        } else if ($sel_val == 123 ) {

            $jdwal_info = 'descr 123';
            $detail_info = 'detail 123';
        } else if ($sel_val == 324 ) {

            $jdwal_info = 'descr 324';
            $detail_info = 'detail 324';
        } else {

            $jdwal_info = 'descr N\A';
            $detail_info = 'detail N\A';
        }

        $this->load->view('sandbox_v/sand_view_2.php',[
                                'j_info' => $jdwal_info,
                                'd_info' => $detail_info
                            ]); 
    }  
}
```

**Model:** named *your_model.php*

```
<?php
class Your_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function your_jdwal($a) {

        // process of getting result from DB over input variable $a (the name of it doesn't matter)
         return $res;
    }

    public function your_detail($a) {

        // process of getting result from DB over input variable $a (the name of it doesn't matter)
         return $res;
    }

}
```

Check it. It works for me.

Comment: let me take a moment to study and apply the code, thank you for explaining :)

Comment: I'm assumming on this step :
/* with your model:
         * $jdwal_info =  $this->your_model->your_jdwal($sel_val); 
         * $detail_info =  $this->your_model->your_detail($sel_val); 
         */
I need to define individual functions for each of this variable?

Comment: @AnggaHaryokusumo, perhaps yes, if you're getting different values for this variables it's better to use separate methods from your_model. Also you could apply one, but it will be complex method. So, yes, use individual methods. I can't help you with your_model, because it depends on settings of your framework. You need one which works already and try to re-write it.

Comment: i've applied the code and modify it a bit
it.. works..? but it doesnt load the view from the second view for displaying data
i tried to inspect it but it doesnt show anything on console log

Comment: check `Network`, not `console`. There you should see your `method` in `controller`. What does it show in `Response` window?

Comment: @AnggaHaryokusumo, check `$this->load->view('sandbox_v/sand_view_2.php',[
                                'j_info' => $jdwal_info,
                                'd_info' => $detail_info
                            ]); ` this part, you should have this file in this path. I'm saying, it works for me. Check it twice

Comment: it shows page not found, so i tried to change the address on the JS to 
url : base_url().'Tour/s1'  (tour is the folder name, and also the controller also named Tour).
it stopped showing page not found, but instead ive got something like this : SyntaxError: missing name after . operator
im assuming the problem lies on the url?

Comment: @AnggaHaryokusumo, yes, url is wrong. See alert with `base_url()` and try to make valid url, pay attention to `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this code, reference in [W3schools Jquery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn_form_submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
           cache:false,
           type:"POST"
           //equivalent of action attribute in form tag
           url:"path/to/your/php/"
           data: $("my_form").serialize(),
           success: function(data){
               //returns data from php if success
           }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: He said that he was new to ajax, and I suggest using the jquery ajax code. I also provide a reference from where he can learn it more. As I do not provide all the answers so he has room to learn more. @AksenP how did you come up with your answer.

Comment: Nice help. In this task he doesn't need `serialize()` and any `buttons`. If everyone will provide such suggestion as you did then this web will become useless. He wrote **without reloading the page / submit button**

Comment: i'm sorry but i need the one without reloading the page, but thank you for replying my question :)